# Download File from AWS S3 using Presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a large file using the AWS S3 URL that looks like the following,
https://downloadfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/client_for....

Supposedly these files can be downloaded by just clicking them or through a Linux terminal. I've tried both but they are not working, getting the AccessDenied message. Does anyone have any insight into solving this problem?

Comment: You have to be more specific. " I've tried both" - tried how exactly? What terminal command did you use? Is that your own URL? Did you generate it?

Comment: The URL link was created by ITS and was sent to us via email. When I click the URL link and get the access denied message and on Linux terminal, I used wget -O myfile.tar "URL" and got the http 404 error message.

Comment: S3 pre-signed URLs are often temporary. Probably the link already expired.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking exactly but was told they renewed the URL link a few hours ago.

Comment: You have to ask them, why it does not work. Maybe they have wrong permissions. Only they can check it.

Comment: "they renewed the URL link" The link itself includes the expiration information, if they renewed it, they would have generated a new link you need to use.